# How to pass more than 1 arguments in jQuery each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments, each

How can I pass more than the index and element to the jQuery's each() function?
I'm trying to archive something like this:

```
function HelloWorld() {
   this.foo = function(obj) {
      console.log(obj);
   }

   this.test = function(className) {
      var that = this; // I need HelloWorld inside
      $("."+className).each(function(hw) {
          hw.foo(this);
      }(that));
   }
}
```

Then somewhere in the page, lets say i have a dozen elements with a specific class name.

Ex:

```
<div class="helloworld" data-test="1"/>
<div class="helloworld" data-test="2"/>
<div class="helloworld" data-test="3"/>
<div class="helloworld" data-test="4"/>
```

In a js call, I would do:

```
new HelloWorld().test("helloworld");
```

However, when i am inside the each function, **`this`**, became the global this of the whole page, I needed it to be the `this` of the jQuery element from `$("."+className)`.

If i don't pass `that` at the end of the anonymous function, then `this` would be the element from `$("."+className)`.

Comment: You're not really doing it correctly, what makes you think you can chain `foo()` to a DOM element ?

Comment: Note that a DIV is not a self closing element ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`that` is in a higher scope, so it's already available inside the each loop :

```
function HelloWorld() {
   this.foo = function(obj) {
      console.log(obj);
   }

   this.test = function(className) {
      var that = this;
      $("."+className).each(function(index, elem) {
          that.foo(elem);
      });
   }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vNckf/)

Answer (score 2):

You have an error here:

```
      var that = this;
      $("."+className).each(function(hw) {
          hw.foo(this);
      }(that));
```

This part is not good:

```
      }(that));
```

All variables from higher closure are already available, you don't need to pass it in any way.

It should be like this:

```
      var that = this;
      $("."+className).each(function(index, elm) {
          // `this` here is element of className
          // `elm` here is the same as this
          // `that` here is what `this` was in higher closure
          // `index` here is the number of the element in a sequence

      });
```